# Crear lista en python

Tags: python

Quiero crear una lista en python y llenarla con los valores inferiores a la variable **n** empezando siempre por el 0.

ejemplo:

```
n = 3
lista = [0,1,2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma más clásica de resolverlo:

```
n = 5
lista = list(range(0, n))
```

[`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) es un generador de secuencias, en este caso una que va de 0 a n, y el resultado lo transformamos finalmente en una lista

Comment: Sin duda, una fórmula mucho más *pythonica*

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado:

```
list = []
n = 0
while n < 5:
    list.append(n)
    n = n+1
print (list)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa, sin usar sumas:

```
n = 5
lista = []
while len(lista) < n:
    lista.append(len(lista))

print(lista)
```

produce

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```